# defined var is null (document.getElementById('existingDiv'))

Tags: javascript

In my HTML file I have a div with

```
<div id="game">a div inside here</div>
```

At the top of my JS file I have (outside of any functions)

```
var gameDiv = document.getElementById('game');
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

in one of my functions (that is run by clicking a button after the page has loaded)

```
newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'displayCards');
newDiv.innerHTML = 'some stuff.';
gameDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

When I run it, Firebug says gameDiv is null :(

Any ideas? I'm new to JS and still trying to figure out the "everything is an object" thing

Comment: Do you have a div with id='game' in your HTML?

Comment: Most likely you're trying to run your initial script before the element exists. The page and scripts load in order from top to bottom, so if the script is above the `game` element, then that means it's running before the `game` element has been loaded. To remedy this, put your script inside the `<body>`, but at the very end of it, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: ...ultimately, because you didn't provide your HTML, we can only guess at the exact reason.

Comment: Sorry guys, I had to edit it to get the HTML to display, but the answers so far are correct. I moved the JS file include to the bottom of my HTML file and it works fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is running before the DOM is loaded.  You should either move the javascript to after the element is declared or have it in a function that is called when the page is loaded (body.onload should work).

Answer (score 1):

When you run:

```
var gameDiv = document.getElementById('game');
```

There element "game" has not yet been rendered in the HTML, so it fails.